# JpaSystemException while trying to run stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, database-cursor

I am trying to run a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure from Spring code.

When I run this in a SQL client e.g. RazorSQL I get a bunch of xmls (which is expected).

```
USE [TABLE78]
GO
DECLARE    @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_GetType]
        @TRAN_ID = 48
GO
```

However when I try to do this via my StoredProcedureQuery I am having issues.

Here is my repository:

```
@Repository
public class TransactionRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Integer getTransaction(int tranId) {
        List result = null;
        StoredProcedureQuery
                storedProcedureQuery = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getType");
        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("return_value", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("tran_id", tranId);
        List<Object[]> userList =  storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();
        return 1; //ignore
    }
}
```

And here is the entity (I am not yet sure how to map all those xmls to one class - but will cross the bridge once this issue is fixed):

```
Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
                                     @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getType",
                                                                procedureName = "sp_GetType",
                                                                parameters = {
                                                                        @StoredProcedureParameter(
                                                                                mode = ParameterMode.IN,
                                                                                name = "tran_id", type = Integer.class)
                                                                })
                             })
public class TypeHeader implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String TransactionTimeStamp;
    private String Type;
}
```

And the error I get is

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:351)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:250)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.jdac.rest.repository.TransactionRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ece3b2d.getTransaction(<generated>)
    at com.jdac.rest.repository.TransactionRepositoryTest.testGet(TransactionRepositoryTest.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:631)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputParameterValue(ProcedureCallImpl.java:669)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:428)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.jdac.rest.repository.TransactionRepository.getTransaction(TransactionRepository.java:33)
    at com.jdac.rest.repository.TransactionRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$296fb70.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Must declare the scalar variable "@P0".
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.processOutput(MSCursorResultSet.java:943)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.cursorCreate(MSCursorResultSet.java:541)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.<init>(MSCursorResultSet.java:154)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.execute(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:787)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56)
    ... 68 more
```

I am using jtds 1.3.1 and Spring Boot 2.1.6.

Here is my spring profile:

```
spring:   profiles: dev   datasource:
    driver-class-name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://p234ttw:1433;databaseName=master;useNTLMv2=true;domain=jdac;useCursors=true
    username: 
    password: 
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1   jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    database: sql_server
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you could post your whole project to GitHub, it would be easy to investigate. But obviously the problem is with passing stored-proc parameter from JPA. My first heuristic will be about non-matching parameter names, but it would be much easier when having a complete project and able to view id in IDE.

Comment: I edited the sproc - that is not the issue and this project is not in github

Comment: The issues is of course not in your manual SP code, but in procedure code that JPA implementation generates. Have you watched the generated sql of the procedure via turning `hibernate.show_sql` to `true`? Is there `@P0` present there?

Comment: My regular heuristic is that you should declare the out parameter as `@StoredProcedureParameter` as well. Take a look at the example here -- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/named-stored-procedure.html.

Comment: This is what I see when I declare the cursor as a `@StoredProcedureParameter`

`Parameter #13 has not been set.
2019-06-27 20:40:54.641 DEBUG 12886 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : {call spn_GetTransactionDataByType(?,?)}
Hibernate: {call spn_GetTransactionDataByType(?,?)}
2019-06-27 20:40:54.641  WARN 12886 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07000
2019-06-27 20:40:54.641 ERROR 12886 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Parameter #13 has not been set.`